# Capifony setfacl permissions: "Operation not permitted"

Tags: permissions, nginx, capistrano, acl, capifony

I have a user `didongo` (user & group `didongo`), and the nginx server (user & group `www-data`). I've setup Capifony to login as `didongo` user: the first time I deploy `setfacl` command works ok (while the logs folder is empty). But after the web application, served by nginx, has generated some logs (prod.log) the very next deploy fails, with an `setfacl` error.

I'm sure I'm doing a noob error with the permissions between the user and the web server, but I don't see what error. I see that `didongo` should not be able to change permissions of a file he hasn't permissions to. But then, how I'm supposed to configure the server or Capifony?

Thanks!

Relevant (hope so) Capifony deploy.rb config:

```
set :user,                  "didongo"
set :webserver_user,        "www-data"
set :permission_method,     :acl
set :use_set_permissions,   true

set :shared_children,       [app_path + "/logs", web_path + "/uploads", "vendor"]
set :writable_dirs,         ["app/cache", "app/logs"]
```

This is the Capifony error:

```
$ setfacl -R -m u:didongo:rwx -m u:www-data:rwx /home/didongo/staging/shared/app/logs
setfacl: /home/didongo/staging/shared/app/logs/prod.log: Operation not permitted
```

Some data on the ACL:

```
$ getfacl app/logs

# file: logs
# owner: didongo
# group: didongo
user::rwx
user:www-data:rwx
user:didongo:rwx
group::rwx
mask::rwx
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:user:www-data:rwx
default:user:didongo:rwx
default:group::rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::r-x

# file: logs/prod.log
# owner: www-data
# group: www-data
user::rw-
user:www-data:rwx               #effective:rw-
user:didongo:rwx                #effective:rw-
group::rwx                      #effective:rw-
mask::rw-
other::r--
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I managed this creating different PHP-FPM pools with the same permissions as the user. This way I can have different users separated from each other. And as a bonus deploy.rb is simplified.

Answer (score 3):

Try this once with sudo and after you will no need to use sudo

```
sudo sh -c 'setfacl -R -m u:didongo:rwX -m u:www-data:rwX /home/didongo/staging/shared/app/logs'
```

Because you need to set `x+` permissions, read this [What is trailing Plus indicates](http://www.linuxnix.com/2011/12/trailing-drwxr-xr-x-linux-permissions.html)

Answer (score 1):

The problem here, is that `prod.log` file was created automatically so its owner is `www-data`. Capifony runs deployment as `didongo` user. One user can't do `setfacl` to the other owner's file.

So just add `didongo` to the group `www-data`: `sudo adduser didongo www-data`