# Capifony setfacl log file permissions

Tags: linux, symfony, permissions, capistrano, capifony

I'm running ubuntu with user ubuntu with apache 2 server.
I'm trying to run a symfony 2 application through capifony (capistrano) for symfony.
All runs very well except when a log file exist:

```
setfacl: /srv/mydomain.com/shared/app/logs/prod.log: Operation not permitted
```

failed:
    sh -c 'setfacl -R -m u:ubuntu:rwx -m u:www-data:rwx /srv/mydomain.com/shared/app/log

I already added with user ubuntu to www-data group.
Acl data:

```
$ getfacl app/logs

# file: app/logs
# owner: ubuntu
# group: ubuntu
user::rwx
user:www-data:rwx
user:ubuntu:rwx
group::rwx
mask::rwx
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:user:www-data:rwx
default:user:ubuntu:rwx
default:group::rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::r-x

# file: app/logs/prod.log
# owner: www-data
# group: www-data
user::rw-
user:www-data:rwx   #effective:rw-
user:ubuntu:rwx     #effective:rw-
group::rwx      #effective:rw-
mask::rw-
other::r--
```

Some help is welcome...
Thanks!

Comment: It appears to be broken. It seems that we may need to use sudo (`:user_sudo, true`) or use a different permissions setup.

Comment: Just answered in another question http://stackoverflow.com/a/19784766/815295

Comment: See [Symfony2 Capifony deploy setfacl Operation not permitted on cache directory](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27513136/1237411)