# Symfony2 Capifony deploy setfacl Operation not permitted on cache directory

Tags: symfony, ubuntu, permissions, acl, capifony

I am deploying my Symfony2 web app onto an Apache web server, on an Ubuntu machine, hosted on AWS, using Capifony multistage deploy.

I have user set

```
set :user,        "ubuntu"
```

And writable directory for cache set like so

```
set :writable_dirs,     ["app/cache"]
set :webserver_user,    "www-data"
set :use_set_permissions, true
set :permission_method, :acl
```

Everything is deploying fine apart from when this is run

```
executing "setfacl -R -m u:ubuntu:rwx -m u:www-data:rwx /var/www/releases/20140310012814/app/cache"
```

I get multiple Operation not permitted errors such as

```
setfacl: /var/www/releases/20140310012814/app/cache/prod/classes.php: Operation not permitted
```

It seems that the user, presumably 'www-data', cannot set permissions on files created by 'ubuntu'. However, I have run the following on the server from the /var/www/current directory, but I'm not entirely sure what they do:

```
sudo setfacl -R -m u:www-data:rwX -m u:`whoami`:rwX app/cache
sudo setfacl -dR -m u:www-data:rwx -m u:`whoami`:rwx app/cache
```

Here is some acl info

```
getfacl app/cache

# file: app/cache
# owner: ubuntu
# group: ubuntu
user::rwx
user:www-data:rwx
user:ubuntu:rwx
group::rwx
mask::rwx
other::rwx
default:user::rwx
default:user:www-data:rwx
default:user:ubuntu:rwx
default:group::rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::rwx
```

I have had a look at a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14718533/capifony-setfacl-permissions-operation-not-permitted) Should I run something similar? such as:

```
sudo sh -c 'setfacl -R -m u:ubuntu:rwX -m u:www-data:rwX /var/www/current/app/cache'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Capifony has a cookbook entry explaining how to [automatically set proper permissions](http://capifony.org/cookbook/set-permissions.html). Basically what you need is this:

```
set :writable_dirs,       ["app/cache", "app/logs"]
set :webserver_user,      "www-data"
set :permission_method,   :acl
set :use_set_permissions, true
```

`:use_sudo` doesn't need to be `true` as long as the `:writable_dirs` are owned by `:user`.

#### The problem

> setfacl: /var/www/releases/20140310012814/app/cache/prod/classes.php: Operation not permitted

This message indicates that the cache directory isn't empty when the task is run (`setfacl` operates on `prod/classes.php` in that directory), which is *not* owned by `:user` (`setfacl` is not permitted).

The fact that the file is not owned by `:user` is quite normal because the webserver will create a lot of cache files, which make them owned by `:webserver_user`.

The strange thing here is that the cache directory isn't empty. Normally a new release should have an empty cache directory. A common cause for this is that the cache directory is shared, meaning you've added it to `:shared_children`. If so, please remove it. The cache directory shouldn't be shared.

If this is not the case, then try to find out why the cache directory isn't empty when the `setfacl` task is run. Maybe other tasks are running to soon.

#### Writable shared children

What if you actually want a shared directory to be writable for the webserver? This is actually very common, think of a `media` or `uploads` directory that should be shared.

The permissions should be set on the actual shared directory, not the symlink in the release directory. Capifony takes care of this for you, as long as the exact same phrase in `:writable_dirs` is also in `:shared_children`.

```
# this will work:
set :shared_children, ["web/uploads"]
set :writable_dirs,   ["web/uploads"]

# this will also work:
set :web_path,        "web"                    # is default
set :shared_children, [web_path + "/uploads"]
set :writable_dirs,   ["web/uploads"]

# this will not:
set :web_path,        "web"                    # is default
set :shared_children, [web_path + "/uploads"]
set :writable_dirs,   ["web/uploads/"]         # trailing /
```

Please check if the directory mentioned in the error is the actual shared directory (not the symlink).

The owner of the shared directory must be the user that will run the `setfacl` command. In other words, it must be `:user`. When you've changed the value of `:user`, or have had `:use_sudo` enabled in the past, this could cause issues. Please check if the directories (as set in `:writable_dirs`) are indeed owned by `:user`.

Capifony will perform a check if the permissions are already set. If so, it won't try to do it again. This is done with the following command:

```
getfacl --absolute-names --tabular #{dir} | grep #{webserver_user}.*rwx | wc -l"
```

Try to run this command manually (replace `#{dir}` and `#{webserver_user}` with the actual values) to see the outcome. If it yields no results, then Capifony assumes the permissions have not yet been set, and will try to do so.

In that case, manually check the permissions with `getfacl`. If they are indeed incorrect, manually set them (again, replace `#{user}`, `#{webserver_user}` and `#{dir}`) using "the power of root":

```
sudo setfacl -R -m u:#{user}:rwX -m u:#{webserver_user}:rwX #{dir}
sudo setfacl -dR -m u:#{user}:rwx -m u:#{webserver_user}:rwx #{dir}
```

Then run Capifony again. If all is well, it should succeed this time!

Comment: What if the problem occurs on a media directory, that is supposed to be shared (it is my case and why I added this bounty). Also, why is `setfacl` is not permitted if `:user` is member of the `www-data` group, which has the write permission on the directory ? +1 for the detailed answer

Comment: It's a limitation of `setfacl` if I'm not mistaken: only the owner of a file (and root) can change its permissions. So it being writable for that user isn't enough (otherwise it would introduce security risks).

Comment: About the media folder: It's been a while when I last checked out Capifony, so I'll dive into it a bit. Theoretically you only need to set the permissions once (when the shared directory is created), and it needs to be done on the actual shared directory, not the symlink.

Comment: If found that when the file has the executable flag, the `setfacl` is possible… but that's another security risk. Anyway, I think the "set it once method is right", because the files in the folder already have correct permissions thanks to the `setfacl -D` command. Bounty awarded.

Comment: Indeed, the `-d` flag (lowercase btw) will make sure that any file/directory created in the specified directory will get the specified permissions.

Answer (score 0):

You have run the `sudo setfacl` on the current directory, but you are receiving the errors on the single releases folders. Anyway, www-data should be the right owner of the cache folder, it is the main user of that dir, in the end!

In our deploy script, we use this:

```
set :permission_method,   :acl
set :writable_dirs,       ["app/cache"]
set :webserver_user,      "www-data"
set :use_set_permissions, false
set :use_sudo,            false
```

I think this is the right solution.